# VUE CLI3.0 Create demo Failed to compile with

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkgEG.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzq2D.png)

```
INFO  Starting development server...

 95% emitting CopyPlugin ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors12:29:34


 error  in ./src/router.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (17:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
|     component: function component() {
>       return import(
|       /* webpackChunkName: "about" */
|       './views/About.vue');

 @ ./src/main.js 6:0-30 10:10-16
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.75.129:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js


{ [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/dollarkiller/demo/testdemo/node_modules/.stats-serve.json']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path:
   '/home/dollarkiller/demo/testdemo/node_modules/.stats-serve.json' }
```

My operating environment：
node v10.15.2
npm 6.6.0
vue cli 3.3.0

vue create verdemo
Bable  Router Vuex stylus eslint 
Report errors

Default default deployment does not report errors

Comment: Check [vue router lazy load documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)

Comment: it's a problem with npm, a workaround is to use either yarn or downgrade to webpack 4.28

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[NPM "create vue project" (with router) - server not starting](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3335)

Here is the answer you want

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Answers consisting of only links are not encouraged here. Provide essential information available by the link here to improve your answer and make it help solve the problem by it's own.